# MS Word: protect header only from editing

Tags: template-design, microsoft-word

I'm creating letterhead template in MS Word for a client. They want to protect the header from editing but allow the footer to be editable. I can't seem to get the Protection feature to do that. It will protect both but not just one. Thoughts?

Comment: make the letterhead jpg and insert the picture (letterhead) in ms word.

Answer (score 1):

Actually no way to be sure else than in OS level protect the file that is in server or belongs to Adminstrator. Otherwise the user can allways write a new file that replaces the old.

But it's possible make things a little more tricky to prevent accidental edits.

Method 1: Create a form that has an editable rich text object, allow user only to fill forms

Method 2: Allow no edits, but insert a linked object that the user can edit and update.

Method 3: A programmed. custom script based system, that disables some normally available controls- for example editing the header or erasing the watermark image.

Method 1 is very restrictive; only one text style is available.

Method 2 needs a robust network system where the links cannot be broken by allowing users to move files. Proper preparations are needed  to keep the links alive. This is beyond the capablities of ordinary user and lightweight system adminstrators, too. A database specialist is needed.

Method 3 needs a competent software specialist, too

Customized systems 2 and 3 become problematic when their creator leaves or needs more money than he has got.

Very weak - but better than nothing - eding hindrance is achieved by inserting a background image. It holds the wanted fixed parts; texts too. Unfortunately the timestamp cannot be a part of a fixed image. In ordinary, non-custom Word that image is removed in 5 seconds.